# Replace a value by that value divided by number of time that value existing in pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe as follows

```
ID    Unit_ID       Price
1     1             50
2     2             40
3     1             10000
3     2             10000
3     3             10000
3     4             10000
6     1             10000
8     3             10000
```

From the above dataframe I want to replace the Price = 10000
By the count of rows having same ID and Price = 10000, here that count = 4

Expected Output:

```
  ID    Unit_ID       Price
    1     1             50
    2     2             40
    3     1             2500
    3     2             2500
    3     3             2500
    3     4             2500
    6     1             10000
    8     3             10000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create mask and divide filtered rows by count of `True`s values by `sum`:

```
mask = df.Price == 10000

df.loc[mask, 'Price'] /= mask.sum()
#same like
#df.loc[mask, 'Price'] = df.loc[mask, 'Price'] / mask.sum()
print (df)
   ID  Unit_ID   Price
0   1        1    50.0
1   2        2    40.0
2   3        1  2500.0
3   3        2  2500.0
4   3        3  2500.0
5   3        4  2500.0
```

If want to divide all values by their counts:

```
df['Price'] /= df.groupby(by="Price")['Price'].transform('size')
```

EDIT:

```
df['Price'] /= df.groupby(by=["ID", "Price"])['Price'].transform('size')
print (df)
   ID  Unit_ID    Price
0   1        1     50.0
1   2        2     40.0
2   3        1   2500.0
3   3        2   2500.0
4   3        3   2500.0
5   3        4   2500.0
6   6        1  10000.0
7   8        3  10000.0
```

Comment: edited the question, replace the price only if the same ID with same price

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace the rows with 10000, you can do:

```
df.loc[df.Price==10000, 'Price']=10000/len(df.loc[df.Price==10000])
```

If you want to divide every row with the value count, you can use groupby and transform:

```
df.Price = df.groupby(by="Price").Price.transform(lambda x: x/len(x))


    ID  Unit_ID Price
0   1   1       50
1   2   2       40
2   3   1       2500
3   3   2       2500
4   3   3       2500
5   3   4       2500
```